# bootstrap vue what does the site use for the search results popup

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

Which bootstrap vue component does the [bootstrap vue](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/) site use?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/algolia/docsearch it sadly looks not to be a bootstrap-vue element